# Calling OpenCart library functions in a PHP file outside of the framework

Tags: php, opencart

In a controller, I can easily call a function like this

```
$this -> user->login('username','password');
```

But outside of the framework in a separate PHP file, how can I access that method? I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mydir/opencart/system/library/user.php');

$userobj=new User();
$userobj->login('username','password');
```

Can you please help?

Edit/Update: Here is what's inside my startup.php file:

```
<?php
// Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Check Version
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.1.0', '<') == true) {
    exit('PHP5.1+ Required');
}

// Register Globals
if (ini_get('register_globals')) {
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
    ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');

    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
    session_start();

    $globals = array($_REQUEST, $_SESSION, $_SERVER, $_FILES);

    foreach ($globals as $global) {
        foreach(array_keys($global) as $key) {
            unset(${$key}); 
        }
    }
}

// Magic Quotes Fix
if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    function clean($data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[clean($key)] = clean($value);
            }
        } else {
            $data = stripslashes($data);
        }

        return $data;
    }           

    $_GET = clean($_GET);
    $_POST = clean($_POST);
    $_REQUEST = clean($_REQUEST);
    $_COOKIE = clean($_COOKIE);
}

if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}

// Windows IIS Compatibility  
if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) { 
    if (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace('\\', '/', substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0 - strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
    }
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'])) {
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace('\\', '/', substr(str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']), 0, 0 - strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
    }
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) { 
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1); 

    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
    } 
}

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = getenv('HTTP_HOST');
}

// Helper
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/json.php'); 
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/utf8.php'); 

// Engine
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/action.php'); 
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/controller.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/front.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/loader.php'); 
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/model.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'engine/registry.php');

// Common
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cache.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/url.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/config.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/db.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/document.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/encryption.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/image.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/language.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/log.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/mail.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/pagination.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/request.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/response.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/session.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/template.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/openbay.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/ebay.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/amazon.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/amazonus.php');
?>
```

Comment: Why didn't it work? Most probably you are missing also other libraries. Instead of including only the certain class, you'd better include `system/startup.php` that will include all the OpenCart system libraries for you.

Comment: @shadyxx Can you please give me a code example? I am a novice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mydir/opencart/system/library/user.php');
```

(including the `user` class *only*), include the `startup.php` that will load all the system classes from OpenCart (may be unwanted or may collide with the scope of project where you need to use those OpenCart classes, but this could be fixed when problems occur). You would need to include the OpenCart's `config.php` as well to make sure that OpenCart's DB class will have the required constants for connecting to DB defined. You may want to do it in *clear* way by checking whether the files exist first:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mydir/opencart/';

if (file_exists($root . 'config.php')) {
    require_once($root . 'config.php');
}
if (file_exists($root . 'system/startup.php')) {
    require_once($root . 'system/startup.php');
}
if (file_exists($root . 'system/library/user.php')) {
    require_once($root . 'system/library/user.php');
}
```

Then you can try to login your user:

```
$user = new User();
if ($user->login('username','password')) {
    echo 'User was logged in successfully';
} else {
    echo 'User not found or username or password do not match.';
}
```

That would be for a *code example*.

Pleaser, take a look into `admin/index.php` how all the required classes are instantiated prior to creating the `User` object.

```
$registry = new Registry();

$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);

$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);

// ... do the same for rest of required classes ...

$user = new User($registry);
```

Comment: Thank you but the code sample doesn't work. It says " Class 'User' not found in ...". I have verified the path.

Comment: Added the contents of startup.php file in the question.

Comment: Oh, yes, I have now realized that class `user` is not included in the startup... Please, include it once more separately under the `starup.php` `require_once`. Check my updated answer (first code block)

Comment: Now, the errors I get are:

Warning: Missing argument 1 for User::__construct(), called in /home/wwwlnydt/public_html/sandbox/opencart/ocservice/json.php on line 69 and defined in /home/wwwlnydt/public_html/sandbox/opencart/system/library/user.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: registry in /home/wwwlnydt/public_html/sandbox/opencart/system/library/user.php on line 8

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/wwwlnydt/public_html/sandbox/opencart/system/library/user.php on line 8

Comment: Seems like the $registry argument needs to be passed. Not sure where to get it from.

Comment: Ok. Seems like global $registry fetches it from me. Still getting this error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/wwwlnydt/public_html/sandbox/opencart/system/library/user.php on line 8