# How to call OpenCart model functions in PHP file outside the framework

Tags: php, opencart

I am creating a web service for [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) e-commerce site and I want to call some predefined model function from this file:

```
opencart_site/api/productbycategoryid.php
```

And the public function `getProducts()` from this file:

```
opencart_site/catalog/model/catalog/product.php
```

#### How can I achieve that?

Comment: thanks Akarienta can you help me in code as well

Comment: Not really sure to understand your issue, but in order to use _specific functions_, you can simply require the devoted file directly in `common/header.tpl` of the theme. Something like: `require_once ('functions.php');`.

Comment: [Answer for your question. Answered since 08/2014](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25481350/1264260)